# What is the need to convert java class into xml?

Tags: java, xml

I have seen a lot of places where in the java pojo class
 `@XmlRootElement(name="Class_Name")` annotation is used.

The documentation tells that it is used to convert java class into xml.

But what is the need to do it?
Anybody can explain?

Comment: One possible reason for converting a Java object to XML would be to send it across the network (a popular alternative to XML would be JSON).

Comment: You can refer : 
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Answer (score 2):

There are some many possible reasons why you want to convert java class to XML. But one of the most common reasons, though not necessarily always, is because you have a need to store the class information for the purpose of **dynamically recreating** it somewhere else. That is, there is a conversion and deconversion.

One common example for this is: by passing an XML message through network/web containing the info about that class, the receiver of the message may create a proxy/dynamic class and use the proxy/dynamic class to perform some operations in the receiving side.

There is also another benefit which might come by using XML is that the receiver may not necessarily read or process the converted java class with java. It can be processed by any other languages such as C#, Python, etc. For similar reason, you may also find a class converted to JSON and is passed around.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending java objects over the network it should be somehow serialized into some strings which can be sent over.

There some format to send serialized data over network, so `xml` is one of them because `xml` has descriptive format which objects can be serialized/deserialized from/to it, then it is very used in many languages like java or in many standards such as `SOAP` webservices etc.

Answer (score 0):

For example Product is your target class:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private int quantity = 0;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Setters must be marked with @XmlElement annotation

next we need to do marshalling operation:

```java
File file = new File("test.xml");

SchemaFactory schemaFactory =  SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(product, file);
```